# ASP.NET web.config connection string with CredentialCache default credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

I want create connection string in web.config file with `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`, it's possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrated Security=true; in the connection string, see here for details http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/277181-What-Integrated-Security-connection-string.aspx